# For returns 1 object Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to return multiple data in my Angular view but it only shows 1 objects. So my code:

```
   var url = 'https://yts.re/api/listimdb.json?imdb_id=tt0455944';
   $http.get(url, { cache: true}).success(function(data) {
      var items = data.MovieList;
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        $scope.Tor = items[i];
        console.log(items[i]);
      }
    });
```

As you can see in the JSON there are two results and the console.log is showing me that. But whenever I try to

```
{{Tor}}
```

or

```
<div class="data-box" ng-repeat="item in Tor">
   {{item}}
</div>
```

it only shows 1 object

Comment: ok.. but what is Tor though? Did you check what data it has?

Comment: $scope.Tor = items[i]; it puts the items[i] in {{Tor}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

> var items = data.MovieList;

with

> $scope.Tor = data.MovieList;

Your final code should similar to the following snippet:

```
var url = 'https://yts.re/api/listimdb.json?imdb_id=tt0455944';
   $http.get(url, { cache: true}).success(function(data) {
      $scope.Tor = data.MovieList;

    });
```

Because you are getting your data in an array form, you can directly set the array value to Tor scope variable.

After setting it, the ng-repeat directive will be able to loop through this collection.

Comment: Worked. Will accept your answer in 7 minutes. Thank you.